# What does "to those end" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

A friend said he was deployed in Europe. He tend to have someone to love "at those end".

I'm not sure what he meant in the second sentence. But the part I got is that he would like to have someone to love in some places?

Comment: "those end" is grammatically incorrect, did your friend mean "that/this end"?

Comment: A sailor might boast about (or attempt to *conceal*) the fact that he has [***a girl in every port***.](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2650819/The-sailor-really-does-girl-port-Mystery-Australian-seaman-caught-writing-postcards-EIGHT-girlfriends.html)

Comment: @AndrewTobilko I think his phone's auto correct might have had messed up the sentence.

Comment: "at those end" is not valid grammar. It is probably an error or confusion of some sort. But without more context, there is no way to tell what was actually intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may have misheard your friend, or they may have misspoken.  The intent makes sense but not the words used.